# How do I start a "React and ASP.NET Core" created in visual studio from vscode terminal?

Tags: c#, reactjs

the "React" template no longer exists in the dotnet list of framework, so I have to create the project in visual studio, and then try to open it from my vs code terminal .

When I do create the app, I get two folder, a client folder and a server folder:

I installed the dependencies in the client folder and ran:

> npm run dev

and then, in the server folder I run:

> dotnet run

both are now running in :

https://localhost:5173/
https://localhost:5174/

My question is how am I supposed to view my app exactly?

When I visit my server on 5173:

a page with the following text opens up:

```
Weather forecast
This component demonstrates fetching data from the server
Loading... Please refresh once the ASP.NET backend has started. See https://aka.ms/jspsintegrationreact for more details.
```

When I reload I get an error in my terminal where the server is running:

```
17:19:06 [vite] http proxy error at /weatherforecast:
AggregateError
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5) (x2)
```

When I visit the client on 5174

I get the exact same page, meaning the content is not loading.

Comment: Hello.  I created a React + ASP.Net project in my VS 2022 as you say, but I got the React part configured with Create React App, meaning I got webpack, not Vite.  Still, I think I can give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A project created with Visual Studio will have `Properties` folder, and in it, a `launchSettings.json` file.  Inside this file you'll have more than one profile in the `profiles` property.  Probably 2:  `IIS Express` and one with your project name, in my case it is `ReactPlusNetCore` because that's how I named the project.

Visual Studio Code will read this JSON file and will pick up the second one I mentioned above because its algorithm tells it to use the first profile found that has `commandName: "Project"` in it.

If you compare the 2 profiles, you'll see that the selected one has a different URL to the first one.  Yes, the IIS one doesn't have the URL in the profile, but if you look at the JSON file you'll find it inside the `iisSettings` property.

With this in mind, let's see about React + ASP.net projects.

### Project Generated with Visual Studio v17.2

> This project carries a React project created with Create React App.

Open `ClientApp/src/setupProxy.js`.  You'll see something like this:

```js
const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:5992';
```

You'll see that the port number at the end matches the IIS settings URL but not the other profile's URL, as per the explanation at the beginning of this answer.  Change the port number and retry.

You should now be able to fetch data.

### Project Generated with Visual Studio v17.8.4

> This project carries a React project that uses Vite.

This one is far more problematic even inside Visual Studio.

#### If You Don't Want HTTPS

I created the project using VS' wizard.  I removed checkmark for the use of HTTPS when prompted, but this seems to only work for the .Net project.  The Vite + React project remains in https, so one must remove this manually (I see no point in running SSL locally for the most part; there are very few exceptions where this is needed).

This the part of `vite.config.js` that specifies SSL:

```json
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target: 'https://localhost:5001/',
                secure: false
            }
        },
        port: 5173,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        }
    }
```

Remove the `server.https` property to go back to http, and then focus the attention to the proxy target.  That URL says "https", which I deactivated.  So the proxy URL is wrong even for running in Visual Studio.  Move it back to http.

---

In `vite.config.js`, locate `server.proxy`.  You'll see the target URL has the wrong port number when you compare this to the port number seen in `launchSettings.json`.  In `launchSettings.json` I see port 45242 for IIS, and port 5282 for standalone (Kestrel).  So the target in the proxy needs to be `http://localhost:5282` in this particular case (I removed HTTPS, so this is why I write here http).

> - The port numbers vary project to project.

There is one more reference in the ASP.net project file to the React project URL.  Open it and change it.  It is the value of the `<SpaProxyServerUrl>` property.  I am currently unaware of its purpose.

Once I made these changes, the project almost behaves.  For some reason, even after closing and opening VS, whenever I start debugging (using F5), it insists on opening `https://localhost:5173`.  I suppose this is what I get for going against the majority of people that probably debug using HTTPS.

No matter, as the OP wants to use VS Code, not VS.  At this point I remove the "s" in "https" in the browser's address bar and the project works and loads weather data.  Time to move to VS Code.

Open the solution folder.  Allow VS Code to add the missing assets to run the project.  Open a terminal and root it to the client folder where the Vite + React project lives.  Run `npm run dev`.  Now press F5 to start debugging in VS Code.  This opens the browser using the correct URL and all should be good.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. I don't have a setupProxy.js file in my client dir, nor the `target` variable (I advanced searched to look for it)

in my launch.settings.json, I have three profiles:

first is an "http" one, the second is "https", they're both identical but have different applicationUrl, and then there is the "ISS Express"

When I run this project from visual studio(using the green run button) it works fine, so I don't think it's a configuration issue, the problem is only when I try to run it from the terminal. 

@jose Ramirez

Comment: Ok, then tell me how you were able to create a project that uses Vite.  That way I can try to figure it out.

Comment: According to Daniel Roth, who works on c-sharp, visual studio now initializes React projects with vite. 

here is the github post where he spoke about this: 

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/36969

Comment: Ok, then I might need to update my Visual Studio.  I'll see about that.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to include both types (CRA and Vite).

Answer (score 0):

This answer goes to your initial premise, that "the 'React' template no longer exists in the dotnet list of framework". It does exist, and you can create a react app with asp.net core in the Visual Studio Code terminal with

`dotnet new react`.

You can find the list of templates using `dotnet new list`.

It has a template name of `ASP.NET Core with React.js` with a short name of `react`.

Answer (score 0):

> 17:19:06 [vite] http proxy error at /weatherforecast:
> AggregateError
> at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
> at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5) (x2)

The reason is that the client loads faster than the server. Right click the server project, and execute debug from there, and see if you still get the error.

When the page loads, the weather data will be hard to see, as the color of the font may be silver, and semi transparent. Click down, and drag your mouse over the weather table.